# sorting a 2d data structure in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, 2d, hashmap

I need to sort a 2d key/value pair by the value.  I have read many references about this on the web and have ended up writing my own class to do this using HashMaps(see below).  I put the code into a condensed working class that reproduces the problem with the minimum amount of code so that you can just cut and paste it into your IDE for quick diagnostics.

As you can see, the method that I wrote is correctly sorting the values before they are entered into sortedMap.  However, for some reason, they values are then again unordered in a different way when I try to subsequently iterate through sortedMap.

Can anyone show me how to fix the code below so that I iterate through a resulting 2D data object that gives me my data in descending order?

---

### ***EDIT:*** Re-wrote using TreeMaps, and am still getting a similar problem.  Here is the re-written code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashMapDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Code that creates and populates the unordered HashMap:
        TreeMap<Integer, Double> unSortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>();
        unSortedMap.put(1343, 0.521851);
        unSortedMap.put(1950, -0.301208);
        unSortedMap.put(3667, -0.0280762);
        unSortedMap.put(3879, 0.154724);
        unSortedMap.put(4124, 0.022583);

        // Code that calls the ordering method:
        TreeMap<Integer, Double> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>(
                sortTreeMap(unSortedMap));

        // Code that iterates through the "sorted" hashmap.
        System.out.println("now iterate through sortedMap: ");
        for (Integer key : sortedMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key, sortedMap.get(key) are:  " + key + ", "
                    + sortedMap.get(key));
        }
    }

    // Code for the ordering method. Note that the println tests indicate that
    // this method is correctly sorting the key/value pairs in the hashmap:
    private static TreeMap<Integer, Double> sortTreeMap(
            TreeMap<Integer, Double> input) {

        System.out
                .println("input.size() upon entering sortHasMap() function is: "
                        + input.size());
        int startSize = input.size();

        // create a hashmap to store sorted output
        TreeMap<Integer, Double> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>();

        // repeat the following process once for every key/value pair in the
        // hashmap
        for (int i = 0; i < startSize; i++) {
            int mySize = input.size();
            System.out.println("mySize is: " + mySize);
            double maxVal = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
            int maxKey = 0;

            // iterate through each key in hashmap to find key/value of max
            // value
            for (Integer key : input.keySet()) {
                if (maxVal < input.get(key)) {
                    maxVal = input.get(key);
                    maxKey = key;
                }
            }

            // add key/value of max of that iteration to sorted map and remove
            // from input before next iteration
            sortedMap.put(maxKey, maxVal);

            input.remove(maxKey);

            System.out.println("sortedMap.put(maxKey, maxVal) are: " + maxKey
                    + ", " + maxVal);
        }
        return sortedMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't confuse a variable you named `sortedMap` with the Java interface `SortedMap` :)

Comment: Thank you.  But I just changed the name sortedMap to mySortedMap on the version on my computer, and it had no effect.  Since it is such a minor change, I am not posting it.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Kai's answer _should_ be correct.  When you write data into a `TreeMap` it gets read out in sorted order.  There is no need to call a sorting function at all!

Comment: Oh I forgot to ask: What is your comparison condition?  You still have to write a comparator if you are not using the natural ordering on keys.

Comment: Thank you both for correct answers.  I marked the most explicit one as the answer, and I now consider this question answered.  I remain interested in the topic.  I have it set up to email me if anyone adds other possible solutions.  I wish java made it easier to work with multi-dimensional matrices.

Comment: No problem. If you *really* like this answer, you can always award a bonus "bounty" for being "an answer deserving of more reputation"

Comment: @Bohemian, Thanks for the idea. +1 for giving me another way to give kudos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need **only two lines** to achieve what you want. Here are those two lines:

```
    Map<Integer, Double> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return map.get(o2).compareTo(map.get(o1)); // reverse order of values
        }
    });
    sortedMap.putAll(map);
```

Here's the complete runnable code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Map<Integer, Double> map = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
    map.put(1343, 0.521851);
    map.put(1950, -0.301208);
    map.put(3667, -0.0280762);
    map.put(3879, 0.154724);
    map.put(4124, 0.022583);
    Map<Integer, Double> sortedMap = sortMap(map);

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
    }
}

public static Map<Integer, Double> sortMap(final Map<Integer, Double> map) {
    Map<Integer, Double> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Double>(new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return map.get(o2).compareTo(map.get(o1));
        }
    });
    sortedMap.putAll(map);
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Output:

```
1343, 0.521851
3879, 0.154724
4124, 0.022583
3667, -0.0280762
1950, -0.301208
```

Notes: You specify *how* you want entries ordered in a TreeSet by passing the Comparator you want to use into the constructor. The TreeSet implementation does the rest.

Other notes:

- The best way to iterate over the keys/values of a map is by iterating over `Map.entrySet()`
- Always use the abstract type for your variables - eg `Map<?, ?> myMap` *not* the concrete implementation (ie `HashMap<?, ?> myMap`)

Here's the generic version of the `sortMap` method that will sort *any* suitable map based on the reverse order of the values:

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sortMap2(final Map<K, V> map) {
    Map<K, V> sortedMap = new TreeMap<K, V>(new Comparator<K>() {
        public int compare(K o1, K o2) {
            return map.get(o2).compareTo(map.get(o1));
        }
    });
    sortedMap.putAll(map);
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I tested your suggestion, and it works.  However, the remaining problem is that your suggestion sorts in ascending order.  And I need to sort the data in descending order.  Can you please show me how to change your code so that it alternatively sorts in descending order?

Comment: Thank you.  I tested the code and it seems to work.  I need to log off now.  I will peruse this more deeply next time I log in.  At that time, I will either ask follow up questions or simply mark this as answered, depending on what I find when I have the time to actually pick it apart.  Thank you again so much.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). Its a `SortedMap` that uses the natural ordering of keys. In your case, it will order by the `Integer` key.

It does the sorting for you.

[java.util.HashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is unordered.

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

`EDIT` *After reading the question correctly*

Use a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29) for the TreeMap constructor that compares the values.

Comment: thank you, but I just re-wrote my code using your suggestion and it is still giving me a similar problem.  I posted the re-written code following your suggestions above.  Any further suggestions?

Comment: You can get rid of the entire sorting section. Create a new treemap. Add in any order. Print out the results. See sorted result.

Comment: @Kal no you can't. It isn't that simple.

Comment: @Bohemian -- can you explain why? He is using an Integer which already implements Comparable as key. the keyset should give him an ascending order of integers.

Comment: @Kal read the question, especially the very first sentence: He wants to sort by the map's **VALUES** (not by keys).

Comment: @Bohemian -- Thanks..I need reading comprehension lessons. I will update my answer.